# Limiting bandwidth in htmlunit

Tags: java, upload, download, bandwidth, htmlunit

I'm using htmlunit to make some tests but I don't want them to use all my available bandwidth. How can I set a limit on upload/download speed?

I have found I can get an `InputStream` from a `WebResponse`. I think this could be used to limit download speed, if I wait some time between reads. But what about upload? I have found no equivalent `OutputStream` in the API. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fits your needs but to control network traffic I setup a local proxy server and you can have htmlunit use the proxy.  Within that proxy you can control bandwidth and many other options.

Hope that help.